# Neat long integer representation in python

Tags: python, rsa, long-integer

I am programming simple RSA decryption routine in Python (I am a bit new to Python) and can't seem to find a way to neatly format long integer in my code.
The integer is 2048 bit long and if written on one line extends far to the right. In C such integer would be represented by a word array, which one can write out neatly on one page.
How would I go about doing this in Python? I tried the obvious solution:

```
modulus = 0xaaaaa\
bbbbb\
ccccc
```

This does not work at all. The only thing that I found to work is this:

```
smodulus = "\
aaaaa\
bbbbb\
ccccc"
modulus = long(smodulus,16)
```

Could you suggest a formatting method for a long integer?

Thanks.

Comment: You're asking how to represent a 2,048-bit integer in the source code (as a string literal), right?

Comment: Yes. This is correct. I am asking how to represent long integer as a literal but neatly. So far all the answers are variation on my original string method. I take it there is no way to break up a long integer in an actual integer form.

Comment: Can you post an example of what it would look like in C?

Comment: I cant post C code in comments for some reason. But it would look like array on `unsigned int` with 4 or 8 numbers per row: `0x11112222, 0x11112222, 0x11112222, 0x11112222,`

Answer (score 2):

Python [concatenates adjacent string literals](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation) so you can write:

```
long('01234567'
     '89abcdef'
     '01234567'
     '89abcdef',
     16)
```

Answer (score 0):

howbout:

```
modulus =( 0xaaaaaaaa << 64
         | 0xbbbbbbbb << 32
         | 0xcccccccc << 0 )
```

or, if keeping track of those offsets is undesirable, a simple helper:

```
def longmodulus(size, seq):
    return sum(leg << offset for leg, offset in zip(seq, xrange(size*len(seq)-size, -size, -size)))

modulus = longmodulus(32, 
    (0xaaaaaaaa, 
     0xbbbbbbbb, 
     0xcccccccc))
```

Answer (score -1):

Make your own function which parses a string, and use that to define a global.

```
SMODULUS = parse("""
    aaaab
    bbbbb
    ccccc
    """)

def myFunc(...):
    crypomath_and_stuff = SMODULUS | abc & etc
    ...
```

You might be able to get around making it inline, and avoid making it a global, but that depends if the python interpreter is smart enough to compile functions-of-constants into preprocessed data, JIT-style (and would also depend if the python language's semantics even allowed such optimizations). To experiment with this yourself, you can use `dis.dis` (the python disassembler) to see if the optimizations are indeed being made (or more likely, not-made). You can also make it inline if you don't care about performance at all, or these are one-off calls to the functions which use `parse`d variables.